# Impulse response and amplitude-frequency characteristic of a communication channel

Tags: digital-communications, python, frequency-response, impulse-response, channel

The task is to implement communication system for transmission of 32 multiplexed signals through communication channel represented by copper cable whose frequency characteristic is given by:

$$H(f) = e^{-d\gamma(f)}$$

$$\gamma(f) = j 2\pi f \sqrt{LC \left (1+ \frac{(1-j)k}{L\sqrt{2\pi f}}\right)}$$

where: $d$=1200m, $L$= 0.5 mH / km, $C$=0.04 µF/km, $k$=0.18.

Amplitude characteristic of a communication channel should be analyzed in a frequency range from 0 to 500 kHz.

For the first part of my task, I should plot amplitude characteristic of transfer function in dB and impulse response of a communication channel.

The task should be done in Python.

Professor gave us what he got as plots and I think I should get the same plots as he did.

The plots he got:

[image]

The plots I get:

[image]

This is the code I used

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Given parameters
L = 0.5 * 1e-6  # H/m
C = 0.04 * 1e-9  # F/m
d = 1200  # meters
k = 0.18

# Frequency range from 0 to 500 kHz
frequency_range = np.linspace(0.1, 500.1, 500_000)

# Transfer function y(f)
y = 1j * 2 * np.pi * frequency_range * np.sqrt((L * C) * (1 + ((1 - 1j) * k) / (L * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * frequency_range))))

# Frequency response H(f)
H = np.exp(-d * y)

# Amplitude response
amplitude = np.abs(H)

# Convert to decibels
amplitude_dB = 20 * np.log10(amplitude)

# Impulse response using the inverse Fourier transform
h = np.fft.ifft(H)

# Time array for plotting impulse response
t1 = np.linspace(0.1, 50.1, 500_000)


# Create subplots side by side with switched positions
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 6))

# Plot amplitude response in dB
axs[0].plot(frequency_range, amplitude_dB)
axs[0].set_title('Channel Amplitude Response in dB')
axs[0].set_xlabel('Frequency (kHz)')
axs[0].set_ylabel('Amplitude (dB)')
axs[0].grid(True)

# Plot impulse response
axs[1].plot(t1, np.real(h))
axs[1].set_title('Impulse Response')
axs[1].set_xlabel('t (μs)')
axs[1].set_ylabel('h (t) ')
axs[1].grid(True)


plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

As you can see the first plot is similar but the values on y axis are different
and second plot is not even similar.

---

Do I need to convert the given units to base units as I did in my code,
and if I do , will the coefficient 'k' change?

---

Does anyone know what could I do to get same plots as he does or If someone can spot a mistake in my code if there is one.

Comment: The formula seems wrong. The units don't pan out. Expressions like $\sqrt{2\pi f}$ are nonsense. The argument to the root has units of $Hz$ and you can't take the root of a $Hz$

Comment: Frankly, I would ask the professor for clarification. The equation as written is non-sensical and it's plainly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something off with the units.
$LC$ has unit $\left[s^2\right]$, so the square root has unit $\left[s^2 + F\sqrt{s}\right]$ which doesn't make sense.

In any case, once that's fixed, use standard units:

```py
# Given parameters
L = 0.5 * 1e-3  # H/km
C = 0.04 * 1e-6  # F/km
d = 1.2  # km
k = 0.18

# Frequency range from 0 to 500 kHz
fmax = 500*1e3
step = 1000
frequency_range = np.linspace(1, fmax, step)
```

Then fix your time vector:

```py
# Time array for plotting impulse response
fs = 2*fmax
t1 = np.linspace(0, step/fs*1e6, step)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped.
Can you explain me why did you use fs=2*fmax and why did you use
step/fs*1e6

Really greatful for your help

Comment: The sampling frequency should be at least twice the max frequency, and for the time vector that’s one of the ways it can be constructed based on the length of $H$. The 1e6 is to have it in $\mu_s$.